# Expand polygon envelop to square using decimal degrees(wgs 84)

Tags: math, gis, geospatial, arcmap, gxp

I working in wgs64 gis.
I have the coordinates of polygon given by decimal degrees.

I trying to expand the polygon envelop from a rectangle to a square.
I understand that a rectangle of one degree of latitude and longitude on the sphere has not the same length in km unless it is situated on the equator. 
But I don't understand the math behind how to fix my envelop.

I am doing this:

```c
Envelope contextEnvelope = CurrElement.Envelope;
double Max = Math.Max(contextEnvelope.Width, contextEnvelope.Height);
contextEnvelope.Expand((Max * 15 - contextEnvelope.Width) / 2, (Max * 15 - contextEnvelope.Height) / 2);
```

Comment: Where on earth did this formula come from?

Comment: What is your definition of a square on a curved surface? Same number of degrees of latitude as of longitude? What programming language is this, and what libraries? Do you really mean WGS64, or rather [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)?